# OnlinePlayer Location Loop

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

I have a method that creates a wall and uses the parameter `Location l`. This is triggered when a snowball hits a block or person and creates the wall along the `X` or `Z` axes. My problem is that if I use `Location l`, I can't use `Player p` to get which direction the player is facing and rotate the wall along the `X` and `Z` axes accordingly. If I use `Player p`, I can't find the `Location` of the block hit by the snowball. So to solve my dilemma, I used `Location l` and for when `Player p` was needed I looped through all online player locations and find a player who was at `Location l` and then casted it to `Player p`.

My Code:

```
public static void wall(Location l){
        Player p = null;
        for(Player players: Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers()){
            if (players.getLocation().equals(l)){
                p = players;
            }
            else{
                return;
            }
        }
```

My Questions:

Is this a valid solution to the issue? Was it valid but did I do it incorrectly? Is there a better way to solve the problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution could be extending Location to keep track of the player(s) that are at that location.

```
public static void wall(Location l) {
    List<Player> pList = l.getPlayers();
    for(Player p : pList) {
        //do Something
    }
}
```

Since you're already storing Location in Player, you can update the values whenever the player moves to a new location.

Another solution would be to maintain a Map of Locations and Players

```
Map <Location, Set<Player>> locationPlayerMap //or
Map <Player, Location> playerLocationMap
```

Determining which solution is the best really comes down to factors like:
 "How Many Players are going to be on a Server", "How many Locations are there", "Are Multiple Players Allowed at a single Location", etc...

EDIT:
You can also structure your method like the following:

```
public static void wall(Object o) {
    if(o instanceof Player) {
        //Snowball hit a player, use the direction they are facing and location
    } else if(o instanceof Location) {
        //Showball hit a Location, use some other factor.
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm just trying to use the location to get a player, I don't really need everyone's locations

Comment: I would store a List<Player> in Location then to represent the Player or Players that are in a single location. Whenever a player moves to a new location, you will have to do something like oldLocation.removePlayer(player) newLocation.addPlayer(player). Then you can use Location.getPlayers() to return a List of Players at the location where the snowball hits.

Comment: I doesn't matter when they move, I just need to confirm that they are at location l when they are hit by the snowball

Comment: I updated my answer to include another alternative option of passing in the snowball's target as a generic object and checking the type.

Comment: That's actually a really good idea, but I'm trying to keep my code short, not have multiple methods, I also wanted to know if the code I had would work. If it doesn't, I'll have to do something along the lines of what you suggested

Comment: I would say your current solution would not work reliably for three reasons: 1) if there are a lot of players, the performance would suffer greatly. 2) The idea of multiple players being at the same location means you have to iterate through the entire list of players every time. 3) You have no idea if the snowball actually hit a player or just the block they were standing on.

Comment: the player limit is 25 and there are usually 10-15 people on so i don't think players would be a limit and as long as I have 1 player it should still work fine so would my code still work?

Comment: If the snowball doesn't hit the player but hits the block they were standing on, your code will still use the player. As long as you are ok with that then your code will work.